# SVD not producing reduced dimensions

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn, svd

Running below code :

```
from sklearn.decomposition import TruncatedSVD
import numpy as np
X = np.matrix('1 2 3 4 5; 3 4 5 6 7; 1 1 1 1 1; 2 3 4 5 6; 2 3 4 5 6')
svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=2, n_iter=7, random_state=42)
svd.fit(X)
print(svd.singular_values_)
```

produces :

```
[19.32338258  1.26762989]
```

I expected the each row of the matrix to be reduced to size but instead the matrix is reduced. Can TruncatedSVD be used so that each row of the dataset can be reduced to size 2 instead of the overall matrix being reduced to size 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The singular `values` were printed instead of the `vectors`.  Having two singular `values` is appropriate since the `n_components`=2.

The transformed output would be obtained by

```
  svd.transform(X)
```

or back into the original space as

```
  svd.inverse_transform(X)
```

The last one is needed to perform any statistical comparisons between the original and the transformed matrices.